# Edit user role from an admin panel (Symfony2 and FOSUserBundle)

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, user-roles

I have the FOSUserBundle fully set up with an homemade LDAP Controller that allows users to login with their already existing logins from the Active Directory.

What I want is to allow the admin to edit any user role from the backend. Any idea how I can do that ?
(I don't want to use the SonataBundle).

I already made the FormType:

```php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $permissions = array(
        'ROLE_USER'        => 'Aucun droit',
        'ROLE_CONSULT'     => 'Consultation',
        'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN' => 'Administrateur'
    );

    $builder
        ->add(
            'id',
            'entity',
            array(
                'class'    => 'MainBundle:Users',
                'property' => 'displayName',
                'label'    => 'Choisir l\'utilisateur',
                'attr'     => array(
                    'class' => "select2"
                )
            )
        )
        ->add(
            'role',
            'choice',
            array(
                'label'   => 'Rôle à attribuer',
                'choices' => $permissions,
                'attr'    => array(
                    'class' => "select2"
                )
            )
        )
        ->add(
            'save',
            'submit',
            array(
                'label' => 'Sauvegarder',
                'attr'  => array(
                    'class' => 'btn'
                )
            )
        );
}
```

And the controller, which is what I am really not sure since I don't know when to select the specified user to edit :

```php
public function editUserAction(Request $request)
{
    $request = $this->container->get('request');

    $editUser = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MainBundle:Users')->findAll();

    $formEditUser = $this->createForm(new ChangeUserRoleType(), $editUser);
    $formEditUser->handleRequest($request);
    if ($formEditUser->isValid()) {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($editUser);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->render(
            'ReportingAdminBundle:Admin:index.html.twig',
            array(
                'editUserForm' => $formEditUser->createView()
            )
        );
    }

    return $this->render(
        'ReportingAdminBundle:Admin:index.html.twig',
        array(
            'editUserForm' => $formEditUser->createView()
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: First of all in your code the $editUser contains collection instead of one specific user, you should use ->find($id) and the $id should be in the params of request

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. But how do I do that with a single form ? Is there any way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I solved this.

The BuildForm of the form :

```php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $permissions = array(
        'ROLE_USER'        => 'First role',
        'ROLE_CONSULT'     => 'Second role',
        'ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN' => 'Third role'
    );

    $builder
        ->add(
            'id',
            'entity',
            array(
                'class'    => 'MainBundle:Users',
                'property' => 'displayName',
                'label'    => 'Choose the user',
            )
        )
        ->add(
            'role',
            'choice',
            array(
                'label'   => 'Choose the role',
                'choices' => $permissions,
            )
        )
        ->add(
            'save',
            'submit'
        );
}
```

The function on the controller:

```php
public function editRoleAction(Request $request)
{
    $request = $this->container->get('request');

    $formEditUser = $this->createForm(new ChangeUserRoleType());
    $formEditUser->handleRequest($request);
    if ($formEditUser->isValid()) {

        // Getting the variable of the form
        $selectedUser = $request->request->get('value');
        // Getting the user infos
        $editUser = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MainBundle:Users')->find($selectedUser);
        // Using the UserManager (from the FOSUserBundle)
        $userManager = $this->container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        $user = $userManager->findUserByUsername($editUser->getUsername());
        // Changing the role of the user
        $user->setRoles(array($selectedUser['role']));
        // Updating the user
        $userManager->updateUser($user);
    }

    return $this->render(
        'ReportingAdminBundle:Admin:index.html.twig',
        array(
            'editUserForm' => $formEditUser->createView()
        )
    );
}
```

I am sure you can tweak this to add more roles if you want, like by setting the option "multiple" to "true" on the choice field.

I hope I could help anyone having the same issue I had !